# Computing $P(X+Y \geq3)$

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y have joint probability function

$\displaystyle f(x,y)={\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{x+y} \quad{}\text{ for }\,x=1,2,3\dots,\quad{}y=1,2,3\dots$

$\text{Compute }\,P(X+Y\geq 3)\text{.}$

I tried to do $P(Y\geq 3-X)=1-P(Y\leq 3-X)$

But then it is

$$1-\int_1^{\infty}\int_1^{3-x}({1\over2})^{x+y}dydx$$ which does not converge unless I did it wrong.

Comment: Maybe a transformation of variables could help.

Comment: Aren't $x,y$ discrete? So the integral should be a sum. And it'll be almost trivial because it'll have only a few terms since $x,y$ are at least 1.

Comment: So I could do $1-P(X+Y<3)$? where this is just $1-P(X=1,Y=1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral does not converge because $x,y$ follow a discrete distribution, not a continuous one as Alex R. said.

The probability you want is:

$P(X+Y\geq 3)=P(Y\geq3-X)=1-P(Y < 3-X)=1-P((X,Y)=(1,1))=\frac{3}{4}$

You could also do the following:

$P(X+Y\geq 3)= \sum\limits_{x\geq2}\sum\limits_{y\geq1}$
$(\frac{1}{2})^{x+y}+\sum\limits_{x=1 ,y\geq2}(\frac{1}{2})^{x+y}$
$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$